# Template weirdness

Tags: c++, templates

I have five classes, declared so:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    void fn(X);
};
template <typename T>
class B {};
class C {};
class D {};
class X {};
```

and I have two instances declared so:

```
A<B<C>> abc;
A<B<D>> abd;
```

How can I templatize `fn` so that one must call `abc.fn()` with an object of type `C` and `abd.fn()` with an object of type `D`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a partial specialization of your class like this:

```
template <typename T> class A;
template <typename T> class B {};

template <typename T>
class A<B<T> > {
  public:
    void fn(T) { }
};

class C {};

class D {};

int main(int,char**)
{
  A<B<C>> abc;
  A<B<D>> abd;
  abc.fn(C());
  abd.fn(D());
  return 0;
}
```

If you want it to work for any template, and not just B, you can partially specialize class A like this:

```
template <typename T,template <typename> class U>
class A<U<T> > {
  public:
    void fn(T) { }
};
```

Comment: What about when I want to use types other than B?

Comment: @MichaelDorst: Do you want it to work for A<U<T> > for any template U?

Comment: Yes, @Vaughn. That is what I want.

Comment: @MichaelDorst: I've added an example of how that can be done.

Answer (score 2):

This is not going to be too pretty.

```
template <typename T>
class B {public: typedef T type;};

template <typename T>
class A {
    void fn(typename T::type X);
    //void fn(...){}  // would prevent an error if T does not have type.
};
```

Basically you save the type in a typedef and then use that in `A`. This would error out of course if B does the `T` of `A` does not have `T::type`.

Comment: For the sake of the cut down sample, there are some accessibility problems as well, what with `class` defaulting to `private` :)

Comment: Your last sentence is confusing me.

Comment: You're missing a `typename` as well.

Comment: @MichaelDorst, It would give an error if the `T` you instantiate `A` with does not have a public `type` typedef.

Comment: Oh that makes much more sense.

Comment: This does seem like a bit of a hack. Is there no way to grant `A` access to the sub-template types of `A`'s `T`?

Comment: @MichaelDorst, I don't think so, unless you pass in `B<T>` as the first template parameter and `T` as the second. I'd much prefer this, though.

Comment: @ildjarn thanks fixed! visual studio has gotten me into the bad habit of fixing this via errors than while coding :(